# Why does "for good" mean "forever"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

A very recent and similar [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/40770/10041) was closed asks what "for good" means.  While general reference can answer the question, I became curious as to the etymology of the idiom.  [Googling](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22for+good%22+%22etymology%22+forever) around got me nowhere, which is unusual.  The closest I found was a thread in [wordorigins.org](http://www.wordorigins.org/index.php/forums/viewthread/119/):

> **OED**
>   **for good (and all)**: as a valid conclusion; hence, as a final act, finally. 
>   15.. *Parl. Byrdes Aij*, Than desyred al the Byrdes great and smal to mewe the hauke for good and all. **1603** in *Crt. & Times Jas. I* (1849) I. 25 D’Auval.. is gone for good and all. **1687** CONGREVE *Old Bach.* I. i, Ay, you may take him for good-and-all if you will. **1711** SWIFT *Jrnl.* to *Stella* 4 July, This day I left Chelsea for good, (that’s a genteel phrase). a **1732** T. BOSTON *Crook in Lot* (1805) 37 He was obliged for good and all to leave his country. **1850** J. H. NEWMAN *Diffic. Anglic.* 324 Throw off, for good and all, the illusions of your intellect. **1882** W. E. FORSTER *Let. To Gladstone* 10 Apr. in T. W. Reid *Life* (1888) II. viii. 421 This morning we released Parnell—not for good, but on parole.

However, this only traces some historical usages, and suggests that *for good and all* used to be a more popular version of the current idiom.  Is there anything more substantial?  Why did "for good" come to mean "forever"?

Comment: I doubt you'll get anything more authoritative than OED on this one. It seems pretty clear **good and all** was the "original" - early transcriptions as **good-and-all** suggest it was already considered something of an opaque idiomatic usage around 1800. I'd guess the implied meaning is for *"good people [of fine sensibilities like ourselves], and also for all others [in the unlikely event that their opinions should matter in respect of this issue]"*.

Comment: An alternate parsing would be *for [the] good [of society] and all [its people].*

Comment: That doesn't mean *forever* though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It may be the *for all* that originally carried most of the 'forever' meaning, as in the expression *once and for all*, which covers pretty nearly the same ground. If so, the *good* part may have been largely an intensifier, with a sense somewhat akin to that of *good* in *a good handful*, *a good while*, etc. However, the [relevant entry in the Middle English Dictionary](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=67601432&egdisplay=open&egs=67724487) notes *by gode inspeccioun* 'by thorough inspection', *in hys good lyve* 'during his whole life', and *gode journeie* 'a full day’s journey', in which *good* has the sense 'full, entire, complete'. This is an even better fit with the conjecture, but it could also suggest that *for good* by itself might have carried some of the same sense as *for all* -- the 'completely' part, if not the 'forever' part. In this connection it may be significant that Dutch *voorgoed*, literally 'for-good', has about the same range of senses as *for good (and all)*; unfortunately, I’ve not discovered anything about its history.

Comment: Indeed 'voorgoed' in Dutch stands for: definitely, final, forever, permanently, once and for all. Example: Daar zijn we voorgoed vanaf. - We are done with it for good. http://www.mijnwoordenboek.nl/vertalen.php?woord=voorgoed&src=NL&des=EN

Answer (score 2):

The context is "for good and all" **time.** Which means "forever."

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster defines "good and **_**" as meaning "entirely".  Thus, while I have been unable to sift through to a reference stating the exact origin of the phrase, one might guess that "good and all" could mean "entirely all".  Thus "for good and all" (shortened to "for good") means "for entirely all."

Comment: But we only use *good and _* with an adjective, like *Make that knot good and tight!*