# Where does "for good" come from?

Tags: etymology, phrases

As a foreign English speaker, I always wondered if ***"for good"*** is an old style English phrase, or it is relatively new. For me, it seems like an old style phrase, but I don't know anything about etymology.

Can you shed some light on it?

Comment: Related: [Why does "for good" mean "forever"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/40771/10041)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sense *as a valid conclusion; hence, as a final act, finally* it is first recorded in the early sixteenth century. It remains in current use.

Comment: Personally I think it's a cut-down version of [for good and all](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+good+and+all&year_start=1650&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) (noun,sense:5).

Comment: Indeed. The OED's earliest citation includes 'and all'